# Getting Document type icon for a document in Sharepoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, csom

I am trying to get the icon url/name corresponding to document retrieved from a SharePoint document library using the following javascript code (i am using JSOM):

```
function GetIcon(filename)
{
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var iconName;
iconName = web.mapToIcon(filename, '', SP.Utilities.IconSize.Size16);
var iconUrl =  "/_layouts/images/" + iconName.get_value();

alert(iconUrl);
}
```

i cant observe any problem in the code but it always shows icon name as '0' than displaying the real icon name (i.e. icdoc.gif, ictxt.gif etc).
Am i missing something here?
Please guide me through this.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me. It even works if the file does not exist and with an unrecognized file extension. Also, permissions do not appear to be involved.

If you browse to the page using Chrome and look on the Network tab of the Developer Tools (F12), you can view the raw response of the request. The name of the request is "Process Query". The image below shows the area I am referring to. This should give you some more insight on the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

iconName will be only populated after calling executeQueryAsync

```
context.executeQueryAsync(function() {
    var iconUrl = "/_layouts/images/" + iconName.get_value();
    alert(iconUrl);

}, function() { alert("Errors"); });
```